# Should I use Xamarin or QT for mobile development?

Tags: qt, xamarin

what are the advantages and disadvantages of Xamarin and QT?

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Everything is opinion based IMHO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tried Xamarin.  Qt handles well on iOS and Android.  It doesn't give the exact native look and feel, and going to a bunch of different screen resolutions and sizes gets to be kind of painful.  I recently finished publishing a Qt app using Widgets, no QML, to iOS and Android (and Mac and PC).

The pop up support for iOS is weird.  Stylesheets are very helpful.  Managing the keyboard popping out and the Done button is a little weird.

Overall it still is Qt, and is an awesome cross platform tool.  Signals and Slots are great.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've been learning QML a lot more recently, and it really makes a big difference when making UI's.  And its performance on mobile is fantastic.

Comment: Also popups (QMessageDialog) on iOS are supported better now.